# Java basic time complexity question i can't fully understand

Tags: java, time-complexity

I am confused about the following method time complexity and could use some help, I am not sure if this counts as O(1) or O(n) when the following for loop receives both the starting point and end point as integer parameters, thanks in advance

```
private static int f (int[]a, int low, int high)
{

int res = 0;
for (int i=low; i<=high; i++)
res += a[i];
return res;

}
```

Comment: Why would it be O(1)?

Comment: It's O(n) where n is "the size of the input" being effectively the difference between high and low.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, your input size `n` = `high - low` which is exactly the number of iterations your `algorithm` is executing. Hence the time complexity is `O(n)`

Comment: n is bounded in this case by the size of the array. you should say that "high" is always less than n and maximum value of high - low <= n for all input values of high/low.

Comment: @TomElias no where in OP's question there is specified that n is bounded by array size. Input is effectively a[low] to a[high], irrespective of size of a. In case of Java this is a bug if low or high are out of bounds. But in some languages it is not a problem. And time complexity does not have to look at bugs.